# Iterating linked-list in an OpenCL kernel (svmpointer)

Tags: c, linked-list, opencl, particles

I would like to pass a linked list to an OpenCL kernel and iterate through the list to perform operations on the values of each element.
I allocate each element with clSVMAlloc in the shared virtual memory. Intel's documents suggest that this is perfectly possible, though I can't find an appropriate explanation as to how to actually loop.

```
//real is of type cl_double
typedef cl_double real;
typedef cl_double2 real2;

typedef struct
{

     //  Mass
    real m;
    //  Position
    real2 x;
    //  Velocity
    real2 v;
    //  Force
    real2 F;
    //  Force_old
    real2 F_old;
    //  Bodytype
    cl_char body;

} Particle;

//  Datastructure of linked list
typedef struct ParticleList
{

    Particle p;
    struct ParticleList *next;
} ParticleList;
```

This is the kernel function (the structs are also defined in the .cl file)

```
__kernel void test(
__global ParticleList *pList){

 //  Check if pList->next is NULL
if(pList->next != NULL){

    while(pList->next != NULL){

        pList->p.body = 'Z';
        pList = pList->next;
   }
 }
```

I set the kernel argument by

```
clSetKernelArgSVMPointer(kernel[0], 0, grid[0]));
```

(grid is an array of lists, rather an array of list-heads)

When calling the kernel with

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmd_queue, kernel[0], 1, NULL, &global_work_size, 
NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)
```

it only touches the first element of the list.

Anyone got an idea as to how access the *next pointer of each listelement?

Comment: maybe some alignment issue, different sizes of your structs (try sizeof() both on the host and in the kernel), or different pointer sizes of host and device (32bit/64bit).

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion. Both on the host and on the device, the particle struct is of size 96 bytes and the particleList struct of size 112

Comment: can you also check the alignment, i.e. the difference of the addresses of two consecutive array elements of type ParticleList both on host and device?

Comment: Well, I just passed an array of ParticleList and checked the address on host and device side, this is the result:
    HOST: 040ff000 is 0.0 and 040ff070 is 1.0  |  DEVICE:  0x40FF000 is 0.0 and 0x40FF070 is 0.0 ...now what does that tell me though?